# Break apart a string between multiple hyphens

Tags: php, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
ESD05 - 10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb - ALARM - Fire Alarm - Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to break apart the string based on the hyphens(-) then echo the separate parts, using PhP. I'd like to break it down like this:

```
[ESD05]
[10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb]
[ALARM]
[Fire Alarm]
[Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = "ESD05 - 10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb - ALARM - Fire Alarm - Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM";
$vars = explode('-', $string);

foreach($vars as $var) {
    echo trim($var);
}
```

If you want the square brackets to remain, do the following:

```
$string = "ESD05 - 10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb - ALARM - Fire Alarm - Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM";
$vars = explode('-', $string);

foreach($vars as $var) {
    echo '[', trim($var), ']';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the explode(), example:

```
$sentence = "ESD05 - 10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb - ALARM - Fire Alarm - Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM ";

$sen = explode(" - ", $sentence);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($sen); $x ++) {
echo $sen[$x] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$string = "ESD05 - 10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb - ALARM - Fire Alarm - Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM";

$vars = explode(' - ', $string);
$string = "[". implode("]<br>[",$vars)."]";

echo $string;
```

Result

```
[ESD05]
[10000 Research Blvd Svrd Sb]
[ALARM]
[Fire Alarm]
[Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:35 PM]
```